# Как реализовать такую конструкцию с помощью Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой код только из 3-х колонок. **Как добавить нижний длинный блок NEWS**

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="box">
   <div class="box-header">
    <h5 class="box-title">Average Sales</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="box-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="box">
   <div class="box-header">
    <h5 class="box-title">Average Sales</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="box-body"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="box last">
   <div class="box-header">
    <h5 class="box-title">Average Sales</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="box-body"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h5 class="box-title">Average Sales</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h5 class="box-title">Average Sales</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box last">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h5 class="box-title">Average Sales</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    после всех блоков пишешь такую магию =) <div class = "col-12">
 А тут пишешь что душа пожелаеш)
</div>
```